Apollo-ios query problem - .couldNotParseToJSON
I am trying to learn how to use Apollo-ios library to work with GraphQL API. I created an example trying to run a simple query on free API: https://countries.trevorblades.com. I followed all instructions in documentation link. I downloaded a schema (made sure it is correct by using Apollo studio) and created a basic query:
query CountryQuery {
    country(code: "DE") {
        capital
        currency
    }
}

Afterwards I used the recommended Codegen CLI engine to generate all swift extensions. Everything looks good until I make a request.
apolloClient.fetch(query: CountryQuery()) { result in                           
    print(result)
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        print(response.data)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}

I am getting Apollo.JSONResponseParsingInterceptor.JSONResponseParsingError.couldNotParseToJSON(data: 162 bytes) error. When I print raw response from the server, it is obvious that communication works properly - i get a right JSON response. The problem is in converting JSON into SwiftObject. Since Apollo is responsible for this conversion I have no idea where the problem is.
Raw Response Data: ---
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 81

{"data":{"country":{"__typename":"Country","capital":"Berlin","currency":"EUR"}}}

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Unfortunately, I found no helpful information on the internet.

Please post all the code, including your schema, code from the codegen, and how you init your client. Which lines triggers the error ? how did you get the raw response ?

Finally, I was able to find the problem. Server was returning the response with content-type: multipart/mixed however I was expecting json/application. I fixed this by adding "Accept": "json/application" header into schemaDownloadConfiguration in apollo-codegen-config.json. Then I regenerated all the files and everything works as expected. However, I am surprised why server was returning multipart/mixed by default. By the way I got raw response by adding my own logging interceptor.

Im glad you fixed your problem, but Im confused. You say the server was returning a content-type multipart/mixed, but the response you show in your question has Content-Type: application/json

To be honest I am confused as well. When I used print response - I was getting what you can see. However, when I set breakpoint and checked response.httpHeaders - it contained contentType: multipart/mixed.
